# Rigorous explanation of a conclusion regarding sequences and subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, proof-explanation

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is given.

Let $a_n$ be a sequence and $\limsup_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\alpha>1$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[{n_k}]{|a_{n_k}|}= \alpha$. Therefore, for $\alpha > 1$ there is a $K \in \mathbb{N}$, so that $|a_{n_k}|>1$ for all $k \in K$. And then, the neccessary condition ($a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$) for convergence is not fulfilled for the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, hence it diverges.

---

**My question:**

I am looking for a rigorous and a precise explanation of how does  $|a_{n_k}|>1$ imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \neq 0$ ?

My attempt:

I see how for $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\alpha>1$, there is a  $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|a_n|>1$ for all $n>N$. And so, it can be proven by the limit definiton that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \neq 0$ and hence the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverge. But I  still fail to provide a rigorous reasoning for the above mentioned implication.
Also, it makes sense to me that $|a_{n_k}|>1 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \neq 0$ is true, I just can't come up with a precise argument.

Comment: Could you double-check your notation. Did you mean $\sqrt[a_n]{|a_n|}$ or $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$?

Comment: @AlexR. Yeah it was a mistake, I meant $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$. Thanks

Comment: Suppose, on the contrary $\lim (a_n)=0$. That is the sequence $(|a_n|)$ converges and hence all its subsequences must be convergent which is a contradiction as $ (|a_{n_k}|)$ doesn't converge.

Comment: @Koro How do we know that $(|a_{n_k}|)$ diverges ? But even if we don't know, we can use the fact that the subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit as the original sequence, and since we know $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n_k} \neq 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \neq 0$ which ends the proof.

Comment: @Koro I guess you could just add "to $0$" after every "convergent"/"converges" and you would be claiming the same thing I proposed in the comment above

Comment: Yes correct. Please read the comment as "converges to $0$" in place of "convergent/converges".

Comment: @Koro Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

If $|a_{n_{k}}|>1$ for all $k$ then we have $|a_{n}|>1$ for inifinitely many $n > 0$ because $a_{n_{k}}$ is a subsequence of $a_{n}$. But assume $\lim a_{n} = 0$. Then for at most finitely many $n$ we have $|a_{n}|>1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why is enough to say that $a_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $a_n$ to prove your first claim ? It makes sense to me too, I just want to see a proper reason, that is basically what I am asking

Comment: Because thus anything that happens for $a_{n_{k}}$ infinitely often does so also for $a_{n}$... assume that was not the case. Then for some $N$ we have $|a_{n}|\le1$ for all $n>N$. A contradiction